# Why do people stand for "Hodu L'Hashem Ki Tov"?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, sources-mekorot, shabbat, standing-sitting

On Shabbos, we say the long Hodu L'Hashem Ki Tov. The minhag is to stand.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Subara. 

Hope to see you around!

Comment: Hi Subara, and as @mbloch said, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I've edited your post a bit. Here on Mi Yodeya we try our best to not use yeshivish or "jargon" so users who aren't familiar with the terms can learn easily. Also, there is not reason to put a dash in Hashem. Hashem literally means "the Name" and has no _kedushah_ (holiness). Lastly, if you don't like the edits I made feel free to rollback. I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 4):

Rav Yaakov Bieler [suggests](https://rayanotyaakov.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/prayer-26-psalm-136-hallel-hagadol.pdf) we stand during Hodu (Tehillim 136) because it is called Hallel HaGadol (Pesachim 118a) and parallels Hallel which is said standing. See [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.422.7?lang=bi) Shulchan Aruch OC 422:7:

> מִצְוַת קְרִיאַת הַלֵּל מְעֻמָּד. The mitzvah
>   of reciting Hallel is [done] standing.
>   .

Comment: @subara1836 If you are satisfied with this answer, please consider accepting it! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work